# Handling extensionless images in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image, web

I am converting a static website (created with "Plone") to an ASP.NET project, and the way it references images is strange and doesn't work in ASP.NET.

The structure looks like this: `/images/image.png/image_thumb` and `/images/image.png/image_tile`

`image.png` is a folder, `image_thumb` and `image_tile` are files. What do I need to do short of manually adding an extension to each file and referencing that?

Here is how an image is currently referenced (works on the old static project but not in ASP.NET): `<img alt="Shallow Tiger" class="image-inline" height="300" src="/images/rm/ue147.JPG/image_preview" width="400" />`

Is it something I need to do in Global.asax? or web.config? or IIS?

Comment: Find a way to automate the manual process? Use a [freeware file rename program](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+file+rename+program+for+windows) to rename the images, and use the regular expression search and replace in Visual Studio to change the `src` attributes in code.

Comment: Also, in what way does it not work in ASP.NET? Did you mean IIS? Was the old website running on Apache? Can you clarify that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad design because IIS need some how to know what kind of file is, and is use the extension of the image to do that. With out the extension you have an alternative to add some code on `global.asax` and filter it by the directory as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);

    // if this is a file inside the directory images
    // and did not have extention
    if (   cTheFile.Contains("/images/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        && sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    )
    {
        // then send the Content type of a jpeg (if its jpeg)
        app.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    }

}
```

but I suggest you if this is easy to return the extension on the images, and let IIS handle the ContentType, and the Cache set of the images.

*The code may need some tweeks because I do not have test it as it is.*
Also for this to make work, you must have setup iis to proceed from asp.net the file with out extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't automate your way out of this situation, then I would suggest writing an [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) that reads an image from disk, writes the bytes to the response and adds the proper mime type to the response.

You can [configure a handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in web.config, here's an example:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="GET" path="images/*" type="ExtensionLesssImageHandler, WebApplication1" />
  </httpHandlers>
```